# Will grouped Laravel routes be cached? Where are they cached?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5.4

As stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#route-caching)

> Closure based routes cannot be cached. To use route caching, you must
>   convert any Closure routes to controller classes.

But if I want to group routes I can make the route itself point to a controller (function) but the group will still be a `Closure`

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function() // Closure
{
    Route::get('/', 'Examplecontroller@bla'); // non Closure
});
```

Maybe for research purposes: Where are the routes cached?

Comment: which laravel version you are using?

Comment: laravel 5.4 pro edition (comment was too short)

Comment: @ThomasMoors haha got the joke :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Will grouped Laravel routes be cached? Where are they cached?

Yes, if body of the group is also another group or non-closure like route.

They are stored in `bootstrap/cache` folder.

---

### Behind the scenes

Closure like group (non **cacheable**):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest'], function() {
    Route::get('/hi', function() {
        dd('Hi I am closure');
    });
});
```

Non-closure like group

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest'], function() {
    Route::get('/hi', 'WelcomeController@hi');
    Route::get('/bye', 'WelcomeController@bye');
});
```

In fact second example is a closure (obviously) but (**my guess is**) Laravel will detect the closure contains only another routes (that are "cacheable") and rewrite it behind the scenes to following (this is not precisely correct and Laravel does not rewrite anything its simple demonstration how it might look, in reality Laravel uses `Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection` object):

```
Route::get('/hi', 'WelcomeController@hi')->middleware('guest');
Route::get('/bye', 'WelcomeController@bye')->middleware('guest');
```

And cache it.

My assumption is that Laravel does some kind of foreach + try/catch and if the body of group throws ErrorException (serialisation error) it simply aborts itself and shouts at coder that its not possible.

---

Code for `$artisan route:cache` is [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteCacheCommand.php)

And this is the code that determines if route is or is not "cacheable" from [route.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L814-L823)

```
public function prepareForSerialization()
{
    if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
        throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
    }

    $this->compileRoute();

    unset($this->router, $this->container);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer,  I found out how the route is cached (in `bootstrap/cache/routes.php`): `app('router')->setRoutes(
    unserialize(base64_decode(#BASE64_ENCODED_STRING#));`

Comment: note 2: Even routes like `Route::any(__('routes.account'), 'Somecontroller');` (note the `__()` translation function) gets cached perfectly!

Comment: ammending note 2: it caches too well, for non-default languages it won't work anymore.

Comment: I have that `Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest'], function() { /* ... */ });` with no closure routes inside — still get `Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed` exception :-(

Answer (score 1):

**The Bootstrap Directory**

The `bootstrap` directory contains files that bootstrap the framework and configure autoloading. This directory also houses a `cache` directory which contains framework generated files for performance optimization such as the route and services cache files.

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/structure#the-root-directory)